# AspxCallback EndCallback event doesnt work

Tags: c#, devexpress

I had a working aspxcallback, today it started not working. I tried everything, changed the control, gave it a new name, added a new aspxcallback control. But none of them make it working.

```
<dxcb:ASPxCallback ID="pageCloseCall" runat="server" 
    ClientInstanceName="pgCloseCS" OnCallback="pageCloseCall_Callback">
    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s,e)
        {
            window.returnValue = e.result;
            self.close();
        }" />
</dxcb:ASPxCallback>
```

Thanks for the help.
Mehmet Serif Tozlu

Answer (score 1):

Handle the  ASPxCallback's client side CallbackComplete event instead.  Does it work?

Comment: No it didn't work. I don't know it was working yesterday, and i haven't been writing any code on that page for 2 months. But BeginCallback event works? EndCallback and CallbackComplete events dont work.

Comment: could you please also post the code of the pageCloseCall_Callback event here?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<dxcb:ASPxCallback ID="pageCloseCall" ClientInstanceName="pageCloseCall1" runat="server" 
    ClientInstanceName="pgCloseCS" OnCallback="pageCloseCall_Callback">
    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s,e)
        {
            window.returnValue = e.result;
            self.close();
        }" />
</dxcb:ASPxCallback>
```

First you have to add **ClientInstanceName** Attribute.
Then on the server side, in the event that will trigger your AspxCallBack, you should be calling **.PerformCallback()**  that causes the call of **pageCloseCall_Callback** to take place. NB: ***pageCloseCall1***.PerformCallback() uses **ClientInstanceName** instead of **ID**.

Regrads,
Andoura